# How to get specific array value in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a data table :

[image: table]

When I will click to phase button a form appears like this-

[image: modal]

When I click create phase a form appears like this-

[image: create form]

And the edit phase form looks like this-

[image: edit form]

In those two form there is a field name **project id**. But this field only appears for the first data only in the table.

[image: first data]

Beacause in my v-model of project id field, I only selected index number 0. So what to write in v-model so that the project id field appears for not only the first row or index 0 but for all the rows.

**Full code:**

```
<template>     

      <!-- Main content -->
      <section class="content">
        <!-- Default box -->
        <div class="box">
          <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Project Lists</h3>
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
              <button
                class="btn btn-box-tool"
                data-widget="collapse"
                data-toggle="tooltip"
                title="Collapse"
              >
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
              </button>
              <button
                class="btn btn-box-tool"
                data-widget="remove"
                data-toggle="tooltip"
                title="Remove"
              >
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-body">
            {{ showPhase.phase_name }}
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                <select
                  class="form-control"
                  v-model="pageLimit"
                  @change="changeLimit($event)"
                >
                  <option
                    v-for="(item, index) in pageSize"
                    :value="item"
                    :key="index"
                  >
                    {{ item }}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="pull-right col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                <button
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                  @click="
                    openModal(backendURL + $config.client.clientEndPoint),
                      initData()
                  "
                >
                  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus-square"></i> Add New
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Category</th>
                    <th scope="col">Client</th>
                    <th scope="col">VPN</th>
                    <th scope="col">Node Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Callback URL</th>
                    <th scope="col">Notify URL</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-center">Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody v-if="Object.keys(dataList).length > 0">
                  <tr v-for="(data, index) in dataList" :key="index">
                    <th>{{ previousPageTotal + index + 1 }}</th>
                    <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.category }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.client_name ? data.client_name : "N/A" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.vpn_name ? data.vpn_name : "N/A" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.node_type ? data.node_type : "N/A" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.callback_url ? data.callback_url : "N/A" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.notify_url ? data.notify_url : "N/A" }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                      <p>{{ phaseData.description }}</p>
                      <button
                        @click="editPhaseData(index)"
                        class="btn btn-primary"
                      >
                        Phase
                      </button>

                      {{ phaseData.phase_name }}

                      &nbsp;
                      <button
                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                        @click="
                          editData(
                            setURL + '/' + data.id,
                            backendURL + $config.client.clientEndPoint,
                            formDataFormat
                          ),
                            multipleAxiosHandler(
                              backendURL + $config.server.serverEndPoint,
                              backendURL + $config.database.databaseEndPoint,
                              backendURL + $config.vpn.vpnEndPoint
                            )
                        "
                      >
                        Edit
                      </button>
                      &nbsp;
                      <button
                        class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                        @click="deleteData(setURL + '/' + data.id)"
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody v-else>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="9" class="text-center text-danger">
                      No data found !!
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

              <pagination
                class="pull-right"
                v-if="pagination.last_page > 1"
                :offset="5"
                :pagination="pagination"
                @paginate="
                  getAllData(
                    `${setURL}?page=${pagination.current_page}&limit=${pageLimit}`
                  )
                "
              ></pagination>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->
      </section>
      <!-- /.content -->

      <div v-if="showPhaseModal">
        <transition name="modal">
          <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                  <button
                    @click="closeModal()"
                    type="button"
                    class="close"
                    data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close"
                  >
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                  <!-- <h4 class="modal-title">
                    Project {{ addFormData.id ? "Update" : "Create" }}
                  </h4> -->
                </div>
                <ul>
                  <div>
                    <button class="btn">
                      <a href="#" @click="showCreateForm()">Create Phase</a>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn">
                      <a href="#" @click="showEditForm()">Edit Phase</a>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </ul>
                <div v-if="createPhase">
                  <div class="padding">
                    <form @submit.prevent="savePhase()" method="post">
                      <label>Create Phase</label><br />
                      <div>
                        <input
                          class="form-control"
                          type="string"
                          v-model="phaseName"
                          placeholder="Enter phase"
                        />
                        <br />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Project ID</label><br />
                        <input
                          type="integer"
                          v-model="phaseData[index].project_id"
                          id=""
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Description</label><br />
                        <textarea
                          v-model="description"
                          id=""
                          cols="30"
                          rows="10"
                        ></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <label for="">Doc files</label><br /><br />
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          ref="softCopy1"
                          v-on:change="softCopyAttach1"
                        /><br />
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          ref="softCopy2"
                          v-on:change="softCopyAttach2"
                        /><br />
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          ref="softCopy3"
                          v-on:change="softCopyAttach3"
                        /><br />
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          ref="softCopy4"
                          v-on:change="softCopyAttach4"
                        /><br />
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          ref="softCopy5"
                          v-on:change="softCopyAttach5"
                        /><br />
                      </div>
                      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                      <div class="phase-modal modal-footer">
                        <button
                          @click="closeModal()"
                          type="button"
                          class="btn btn-danger pull-left"
                          data-dismiss="modal"
                        >
                          Close
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          Save Data
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div v-if="editPhase">
                  <div class="padding">
                    <form @submit.prevent="" method="post">
                      <label>Edit Phase</label><br />
                      <div>
                        <select
                          v-on:change="showData()"
                          class="form-control"
                          width="40px"
                        >
                          <option
                            v-for="(data, index) in phaseData"
                            :key="index"
                            :value="index"
                          >
                            {{ data.phase_name }}
                          </option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Project ID</label><br />
                        <input
                          type="integer"
                          v-model="phaseData[0].project_id"
                          id=""
                        />
                        {{ phaseData[1].project_id }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Description</label><br />
                        <textarea
                          v-model="phaseData.description"
                          id=""
                          cols="30"
                          rows="10"
                        >
                        </textarea>
                      </div>
                      <label for="">Doc files</label><br /><br />
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          ref="softCopy1"
                          v-on:change="softCopyAttach1"
                        /><br />
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          ref="softCopy2"
                          v-on:change="softCopyAttach2"
                        /><br />
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          ref="softCopy3"
                          v-on:change="softCopyAttach3"
                        /><br />
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          ref="softCopy4"
                          v-on:change="softCopyAttach4"
                        /><br />
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          ref="softCopy5"
                          v-on:change="softCopyAttach5"
                        /><br />
                      </div>
                      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                      <div class="phase-modal modal-footer">
                        <button
                          @click="closeModal()"
                          type="button"
                          class="btn btn-danger pull-left"
                          data-dismiss="modal"
                        >
                          Close
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          Save Data
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import pagination from "../common/Pagination";
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";
import axios from "axios";
import CreatePhase from "./CreatePhase";
import EditPhase from "./EditPhase";

export default {
  components: {
    pagination,
    Multiselect,
    CreatePhase,
    EditPhase,
    CreatePhase,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      setURL: "",
      pagination: {
        current_page: 1,
      },
      addFormData: {
        add_row: [],
      },
      delete_row_id: [],
      ifHasVpn: false,
      ifHasApp: false,
      ifVas: false,
      serverData: [],
      databaseData: [],
      vpnData: [],
      //for multiple select data store
      server_id: [],
      database_id: [],
      old_callback_url: "",
      old_notify_url: "",

      //Phase
      phase_name: "",
      phaseName: "",
      showPhaseModal: false,
      createPhase: false,
      editPhase: false,
      //for softCopy Attachment
      softCopy1: "",
      softCopy2: "",
      softCopy3: "",
      softCopy4: "",
      softCopy5: "",
      description: "",
      phaseData: [],

      brd: "",
      sow: "",
      srs: "",
      uat: "",
      soln: "",
      showPhase: "",
      editIndex: 0,
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.setURL = `${this.backendURL + this.$config.project.projectEndPoint}`;
    let url = `${this.setURL}?page=${this.pagination.current_page}&limit=${this.pageLimit}`;
    this.getAllData(url);
  },
  methods: {
    editPhaseData: function (id, index) {
      this.editIndex = index;
      //const_this = this;
      this.showPhaseModal = true;
      this.axios
        .get("http://45.114.85.18:8099/api/project/phase?project_id=" + id, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.phaseData = res.data.data;
          this.showPhase = res.data.data;
        });
    },
    showData() {
      this.description = phaseData[this.name].description;
    },

    showCreateForm() {
      this.createPhase = !this.createPhase;
      if (this.createPhase == true) {
        this.editPhase = false;
      }
    },
    showEditForm() {
      this.editPhase = !this.editPhase;
      if (this.editPhase == true) {
        this.createPhase = false;
      }
    },
    softCopyAttach1() {
      this.softCopy1 = this.$refs.softCopy1.files[0];
    },

    softCopyAttach2() {
      this.softCopy2 = this.$refs.softCopy2.files[0];
    },

    softCopyAttach3() {
      this.softCopy3 = this.$refs.softCopy3.files[0];
    },

    softCopyAttach4() {
      this.softCopy4 = this.$refs.softCopy4.files[0];
    },

    softCopyAttach5() {
      this.softCopy5 = this.$refs.softCopy5.files[0];
    },

    addRow() {
      this.addFormData.add_row.push({ url: "" });
    },
    removeRow(key, rowId) {
      if (rowId != "") {
        this.delete_row_id.push(rowId);
      }
      this.addFormData.add_row.splice(key, 1);
    },
    changeLimit(value) {
      let url = `${this.setURL}?page=1&limit=${value.target.value}`;
      this.getAllData(url);
    },
    initData() {
      this.delete_row_id = [];
      this.ifHasVpn = false;
      this.ifHasApp = false;
      this.ifVas = false;
      this.addFormData = {
        add_row: [],
        category: "Internal",
        sdp_or_mife: "SDP",
        has_vpn: "0",
        has_app: "0",
        client_id: "",
      };
    },
    checkCategory(forAdd, forEdit) {
      let event = forAdd ? forAdd.target.value : forEdit;
      if (event == "VAS") {
        this.ifVas = true;
      } else {
        this.addFormData.node_type = "";
        this.addFormData.callback_url = "";
        this.addFormData.notify_url = "";
        this.addFormData.sdp_or_mife = "";
        this.ifVas = false;
      }
    },
    showVpnDropdown(forAdd, forEdit) {
      let event = forAdd ? forAdd.target.value : forEdit;
      if (event == "1") {
        this.ifHasVpn = true;
      } else {
        this.ifHasVpn = false;
      }
    },
    showPlayStoreDetail(forAdd, forEdit) {
      let event = forAdd ? forAdd.target.value : forEdit;
      if (event == "1") {
        this.ifHasApp = true;
      } else {
        this.ifHasApp = false;
      }
    },
    formDataFormat(formData) {
      const _this = this;
      _this.addFormData = formData;
      _this.addFormData.has_vpn = _this.addFormData.has_vpn
        ? _this.addFormData.has_vpn
        : "0";
      _this.addFormData.has_app = _this.addFormData.has_app
        ? _this.addFormData.has_app
        : "0";
      _this.addFormData.vpn_id = _this.addFormData.vpn_id
        ? _this.addFormData.vpn_id
        : "";
      _this.addFormData.sdp_or_mife = _this.addFormData.sdp_or_mife
        ? _this.addFormData.sdp_or_mife
        : "";
      //assign db and server details
      _this.database_id = formData.db_row ? formData.db_row : "";
      _this.server_id = formData.server_row ? formData.server_row : "";
      _this.checkCategory(null, _this.addFormData.category);
      _this.showVpnDropdown(null, _this.addFormData.has_vpn);
      _this.showPlayStoreDetail(null, _this.addFormData.has_app);
      //set old callback and notify url
      _this.old_callback_url = _this.addFormData.notify_url;
      _this.old_notify_url = _this.addFormData.notify_url;
    },
    multipleAxiosHandler(URL_1, URL_2, URL_3) {
      const _this = this;
      _this.$store.state.pageLoader = true;
      _this.axios
        .all([
          _this.getDropdownData_(URL_1),
          _this.getDropdownData_(URL_2),
          _this.getDropdownData_(URL_3),
        ])
        .then(
          _this.axios.spread((first_res, second_res, third_res) => {
            if (first_res.data.data) {
              _this.serverData = [];
              let data = first_res.data.data;
              data.forEach(function (item) {
                _this.serverData.push({ id: item.id, name: item.name });
              });
            }
            if (second_res.data.data) {
              _this.databaseData = [];
              let data = second_res.data.data;
              data.forEach(function (item) {
                _this.databaseData.push({ id: item.id, name: item.hostname });
              });
            }
            if (third_res.data.data) {
              _this.vpnData = [];
              _this.vpnData = third_res.data.data;
            }
            _this.$store.state.pageLoader = false;
          })
        )
        .catch((errors) => {
          _this.showToast(errors);
          _this.$store.state.pageLoader = false;
        });
    },
    getDropdownData_(url) {
      return this.axios.get(url, this.authConfig);
    },
    createFormData() {
      this.storeFormData(this.setURL, this.addFormData);
    },
    upFormData(lid) {
      this.addFormData.server_id = this.server_id;
      this.addFormData.db_id = this.database_id;
      //console.error(this.addFormData); return
      this.updateFormData(this.setURL + "/" + lid, this.addFormData);
    },
    setOldCallbackURL() {
      this.addFormData.old_callback_url = this.old_callback_url;
    },
    setOldNofifyURL() {
      this.addFormData.old_notify_url = this.old_notify_url;
    },
  },
};
```

**Error pic:**
This error is appearing when I am clicking those buttons.

[image: Console error]

Comment: Please insert your table code, I think your problem is there

Comment: But for loop is bringing all the ids from the array. I want to get specific project_id. Not all.

Comment: Please provide the complete data table code as well

Comment: So there is no need to write like this. Create a variable and store your specific project id in it.

Comment: Please show me with example how should I write

Comment: @alprazolam Edited my answer according to your provided code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you just provide the element with `index` `0` in your code, as seen in `phaseData[0].project_id`. You need to provide the `index` to the function which opens your `form`.

I don´t see that you posted your code of the `table`, but it simply would be like `callFormDialogFunction(index)` and passing that index into the form, then using it like `phaseData[index].project_id`.

---

**EDIT: Changes according to your full provided code**

You are calling `@click="editPhaseData(index)"` but you have two parameters in your function:

```
editPhaseData: function (id, index) {
      this.editIndex = index;
      this.showPhaseModal = true;
      this.axios
        .get("http://45.114.85.18:8099/api/project/phase?project_id=" + id, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.phaseData = res.data.data;
          this.showPhase = res.data.data;
        });
    }
```

In this case `this.editIndex` will be undefined, as there is no second parameter. Example:

```
editPhaseData(index) // index is the first parameter
editPhaseData: function (id, index) {...} // id is the first parameter, so id is what you passed as index. The second one, called index, is undefined.
```

In your case it looks like `data.id` in your loop provides the id of the so called phase. So you need to call `@click="editPhaseData(data.id, index)"`. Then in `editPhaseData: function (id, index) {...}` the `id` parameter will be the `data.id` and `index` parameter will be `index`.

But now, as `this.editIndex` is the index of the phase you want to edit, you need to change `phaseData[index].project_id` to `phaseData[editIndex].project_id`.

---

**EDIT 2: Your error according `project_id`**

As you not provided the structure of your data, I can´t tell what key `project_id` should be. So on `phaseData[editIndex].project_id` you need `project_id` to the key, which provides the key of your id. If the key is `id`, it would be `phaseData[editIndex].id`.

Comment: Please can you show me what to write inside [ ] instead of only index 0 ?

Comment: As you posted your table code now, you just need to change `@click="editPhaseData(data.id)` to `@click="editPhaseData(index)`.

Comment: And how to write the v-model to not only get index 0 but all the index ?

Comment: It would be, like meantoined, `v-model="phaseData[index].project_id"` where `index` is the same `index` passed by `@click="editPhaseData(index)`. You need to provide more code for more detail. Provide the full code of `editPhaseData`.

Comment: Ok I am providing the full page.

Comment: Showing an error message in console. I have provided a pic in my post. Could you please check ?

Comment: @alprazolam The error tells you what´s wrong. I edited my answer, but this is just reading the error.

Comment: Ok. No problem. It is solved now

Comment: @alprazolam Fine. Please do not forget to accept the answer and vote it up, if it helped you with your problems.